# Jenkins github pull request builder do not trigger downstream projects

Tags: jenkins, ghprb

I recently set up github pull request builder on jenkins and it works well when I commented the trigger phrase on the PR. But when I tried to run multiple jobs by setting the downstream upstream relationship, I met this problem which is jenkins triggered the job `job A` set up by pull request builder as normal, but wouldn't trigger the downstream job `job B` when `job A` has finished.

Here are some of settings:

In `job A`: just everything on the instruction page of the github pull request builder

In `job B`: Under `Build Triggers` section, I checked `Build after other projects are built` and set the `projects to watch` to be `job A`, and checked `Trigger only if build is stable` (Nothing about github pull request builder on job B)

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this from the upstream project, instead.  From the upstream project configuration, Add post-build action --> Build other projects, then enter the name of the project to build.